Last Sticky Inner Section Not Scrolling in Elementor Sticky Container
Main Section: It has h2 and description -> It was sticky with top:80,
Inner section 1: It is sticky with top:80 and other inner sections too.
Once the inner section 4 is reached his position, then it should scroll to top with Main Section. I tried this, but the last inner section is overlapping with the Main section.
How to resolve it on WordPress Elementor?

You have enough site rep to know that there is no way we can help you with the information you provided. Post your code.

All set on Elementor editor itself

There is no way we can help you unless we had access to your site. Telling us some CSS properties doesn't really help us debug what you have going on.
